# Omit field names from Visual Studio's Navigation Bar?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm a big fan of the Navigation Bar in Visual 2017, particularly the right-most drop-down (an alphabetical list of all members defined by the current class).  This feature would be even greater if only method names were shown in the member drop-down (not field names, which are often numerous & less useful).

Is there a way to customize the IDE to show method names only in that drop-down?  **Tools -> Options** provides a way to turn the Navigation Bar off, but I couldn't find much else in the way of customization.

Comment: Do you mean in the solution explorer?

Comment: Negative....  The navigation bar sits in between the main window (source file view) and the list of open tabs, toward the top of the screen.  It consists of three drop-downs (project selection, class selection, and method/field selection).

Comment: Ah I see what you are talking about. I have no clue if it's possible to filter only methods. I hope it helps.